# Регулярное выражение поиска по шаблону

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Имеется массив строк:

```
$test = array(
'Required route parameter not passed: :param',
'The :property property does not exist in the :class class',
'The requested view :file.:ext could not be found',
'PHP internal call',
'API method :uri: :code');
```

Нужно найти и земенить конструкции вида ':метка' на ':'.str_rot13('метка'), конструкций может быть несколько в строке, вложенности нет. Начинается метка с символа двоеточия, а заканчивается пробелом, точкой, запятой, двоеточием.

Проблема в том, что не знаю как составить "регулярку" для вычленения этих меток.
Также буду признателен за доходчивые материалы по ним, желательно с большим числом примеров.

**Итоговый вариант:**

```
$test = preg_replace_callback('~:(\w+)~', function($matches){return ':'.str_rot13($matches[1]);}, $test);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать это используя `preg_replace_callback()`

```
<?php
$test = array(
'Required route parameter not passed: :param',
'The :property property does not exist in the :class class',
'The requested view :file.:ext could not be found',
'PHP internal call',
'API method :uri: :code');

function str13_run($matches) {
    return ":".str_rot13($matches[1]); // первая группа
}

$test=preg_replace_callback('/:(\w+)/s','str13_run',$test);

print_r($test);
```

[Демо](http://ideone.com/AP1t2M)

- [список функций для работы с регулярками](http://ideone.com/AP1t2M)
- [синтаксис регулярок pcre](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)
- [примеры регулярок](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) (english, там про perl, но как раз perl регулярки используются в php, поэтому почитайте ещё [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: Красивое решение, а вот результат какой-то странный.

Comment: чего странного ? в смысле : нет в начале, я наверное его забыл, или где-то по дороге решил что не надо.

Comment: сжирается символ : перед меткой 
и для красоты заменить использовать closure ф-цию

Comment: а ну символ вернул, а насчет красоты closure, посреди perl функции я-бы поспорил, это не js, тут это не красиво. тем более в php closure работают весьма своеобразно.

Comment: А не. Отбой. Все ок.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Исходный массив
$test = array(
 'Required route parameter not passed: :param',
 'The :property property does not exist in the :class class',
 'The requested view :file.:ext could not be found',
 'PHP internal call',
 'API method :uri: :code');

// Результирующий массив
$result = array();

// Проходим по всем элементам массива
foreach($test as $i) {

  // Находим все нужные нам элементы и складываем их в массив $out
  preg_match_all('/\:([^ \.\:]+)/i', $i, $out);

  // Обновляем блоки замен по требуемой маске. Теперь в массиве $out 
  // два подмассива: $out[0] - элементы, которые надо заменить
  // $out[1] - соответствующие им элементы-заместители
  foreach($out[1] as &$ii) {
    $ii = ':' . str_rot13($ii);
  }

  // Добавляем в результирующий массив результаты замены $out[0] на $out[1]
  $result[] = str_replace($out[0], $out[1], $i);
}
```

Лучшее по регулярным выражениям: книга Дж. Фридла ["Регулярные выражения"](http://www.books.ru/books/regulyarnye-vyrazheniya-3-e-izdanie-fail-pdf-626982/?show=1). Мастхэв.

Comment: спасибо, единственное что надо было вызывать ф-цию str_rot13, поэтому вариант eicto более кошерен)

Comment: Да. У @eicto суперский вариант.